# Express - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined, request.js 31

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs

I have spent too much time trying to debug this but unsure where its coming from or why I am getting this error. 
I am trying to make a simple website to practice react and am trying to get some data from Riot's API.

I tried to use isomorphic-fetch but ran into issues with https so I switched to express.

After switching to express I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined.

I am also using browserify-middleware if that matters at all.

Here is the file that is causing issues.

```
// import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

// var myHeaders = new Headers();

var express = require('express')
var app = express();

var apiURL = 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/';
var apiToken = '?api_key='


// export function fetchSummonerInfo() {
//  return fetch(apiURL + 'summoner/by-name/' + AUserName + apiToken, {
//      method: 'GET',
//      mode: 'no-cors'
//  })
//      .then((data) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
//      // .catch((e) => console.log(e))
//      // .then((res) => console.log(res))
// }
// 

// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
//  next();
// })

export function fetchSummonerInfo() {
    app.get(apiURL + 'summoner/by-name/Faxious' + apiToken, middle,  function(req, res) {
        let body = ""
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            body += data;
        })
        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log(body);
        })
    })
}

function middle(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use Express to *make* requests, not *receive* requests. `app.get()` sets up a handler for *incoming* `GET` requests to the Express server. You probably want `http.request()`/`http.get()` or the `request` module or similar to make outbound requests.

Comment: I didnt even think about that. We have been working on back end using express and I believe thats where I made the mistake that app.get() would make request but it doesnt. App.get only receives a request and does things with that, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Express is a web framework for your backend to handle the request and provide a response not to execute requests. Have a look at routing guide [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

If you want to make requests i can recommend [request](https://github.com/request/request) module which i personally prefer for my projects and it's pretty straight forward. There are some alternatives such as [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) as well.