# Node/Express: How do I separate server side and client side javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building a JS project to learn new skills, and I'm having trouble delineating between the client-side code and the server-side code. The current setup is a node app with ExpressJS as a dependency.

When I run `npm run build && npm run dev`, the base html/css is served as expected, but I get an error in my console from the express script.

> main.fb6bbcaf.js:116 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'prototype' of undefined
> at Object.parcelRequire.node_modules/express/lib/response.js.safe-buffer
> (response.js:42)
> at newRequire (main.fb6bbcaf.js:47)
> at localRequire (main.fb6bbcaf.js:53)
> at Object.parcelRequire.node_modules/express/lib/express.js.body-parser
> (express.js:22)
> at newRequire (main.fb6bbcaf.js:47)
> at localRequire (main.fb6bbcaf.js:53)
> at Object.parcelRequire.node_modules/express/index.js../lib/express
> (index.js:11)
> at newRequire (main.fb6bbcaf.js:47)
> at localRequire (main.fb6bbcaf.js:53)
> at Object.parcelRequire.js/main.js.express (main.js:1)

For reference, I'm still trying to get the example code from the express documentation to run, so my whole `main.js` file looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 1234;

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`));
```

I found a person with a similar issue [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316273/var-express-requireexpress-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-undefined), but what doesn't click for me (and what I can't seem to find a proper question for) is how to separate the client-side and server-side code in my project. I get the feeling that I'm trying to use express in code that's being served to the client, but I don't know where else to put it.

***Is there a best-practice location for server-side code in a project that uses both node and express?***

Comment: The code you show, all by itself, does not create the error you show as there is no body-parser module in that code.  We will need to see THE actual code that leads to that error.  I don't understand why you think this error has anything to do with client-side Javascript.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's all THE js code in the project. I haven't once used the body-parser module. It was installed as a dependency of a dependency. I just started working on the js after finishing the html/css. No need to be snippy.

Comment: If that's all the code you are running, then there is apparently something wrong with your installation.  You need to uninstall express and any other modules in that directory, make sure the `node_modules` directory where they are installed is completely clean.  Clean out your package.json file for your app and reinstall Express from scratch.  I still don't understand at all what this question has to do with client-side Javascript.   All you show here is server-side Javascript.

Comment: And, I'd suggest you just try running `node main.js` to eliminate any other things that might be in your package.json as a source of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Error code say you have problem with  Express and body-parser modules.
lets fix this from beginning.

// creating new project through cmd line

1)cd to project directory

2)create app.js

3)npm init -y  // to create project

4)npm install express body-parser //installing required modules

//open app.js and configure server using below code

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
res.send("Hello world");
})


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

//now run app.js

1)node app.js

2)In browser, head over to "localhost:3000"

This should have solved your problem.
body-parser is used when you have post request to server. It shouldn't show any body-parser error if no post request is submitted to your server.

Comment: What does the -y do in `npm init -y` ?

Comment: -y    its like say yes to all default value, if it confuse you just remove it and use only " npm init"  you will understand what I'm saying

Comment: The `app.js` file I create will be for server-side code, right? So where would I put client-side js?

Comment: when you get a request to server,you have to send files to client,these file should be send through  app.get("/",function(req,res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + "index.html")
})                            you should have already created HTML file and stored in your project folder.  so when you get request at "localhost:3000/" your app.get()  send the  HTML and its related CSS and JavaScript files if you have .

Comment: Note : you don have client side JavaScript because your are performing it at server side itself. there is no need to send JavaScript file to client side